# What's the difference between `hostip` and `windows ip` when set WSL2 proxy by Clash `Allow LAN`?

Tags: networking, bash, proxy, export, wsl2

I have searched and scanned many blogs or websites for “how to set proxy for WSL2”. Such as [here](https://www.sobyte.net/post/2022-02/wsl2-proxy/) or [here](https://isshiki.medium.com/wsl2-proxy-setting-2647a556c5ec).

My confusion is, that I find the following 2 ways can both set proxy for WSL2 successfully when using `wegt www.google.com` to test.

Assume I have `windowsip=192.168.3.3` and `hostip=172.24.80.1` as
[image: Network Interfaces fig in Clash for Windows]

- use `hostip`

```bash
hostip=172.24.80.1
proxyPort=7890 
export https_proxy="http://${hostip}:${proxyPort}";
export http_proxy="http://${hostip}:${proxyPort}";
export all_proxy="http://${hostip}:${proxyPort}";
```

Then the test result of using `hostip=172.24.80.1` is:
[image: Test figure to proof it do work]

- or use `windows ip`:

```bash
windowsip=192.168.3.3
proxyPort=7890 
export https_proxy="http://${windowsip}:${proxyPort}";
export http_proxy="http://${windowsip}:${proxyPort}";
export all_proxy="http://${windowsip}:${proxyPort}";
```

The test result of using `windowsip=192.168.3.3` is: [image: Test figure to proof it do work]

Since I do lack corresponding knowledge of computer networks, I'm very confused about them. Why the ip `192.168.3.3` and `172.24.80.1` are both effective for WSL2 when CFW's `Allow LAN` enabled?

So, what is the difference between the above 2 methods?
And are there any potential differences that may influence my succedent usage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally none. In both cases, the variable has no meaning on its own – it's a temporary definition that is *only* used as a `$variable` substitution in the subsequent `export` lines. (Only "exported" variables become visible to child processes as environment variables; the rest remain internal to the shell.) In both cases, the end result is `export https_proxy="http://172.24.80.1:7890"`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  But I'm afraid that I really want to know the difference between using 2 different IPs, i.e. `172.24.80.1` (v-Ethernet WSL) and `192.168.3.3` (Windows). Why they can both make `Allow LAN` proxy success? I have modified my original question so maybe you can check more details from it. Thanks .

Comment: They both belong to the same system, just on different network interfaces. It's like having two Ethernet ports on your Windows system, each with its own address.

Comment: Thank you, I seem to understand it.